# Run react native app on Android offline

Tags: android, react-native, offline

I need to run a react-native project offline because I can't access the internet very often and I need to develop a simple app OFFLINE most of the time. I already created a base app using react-native init but can't be online all the time I need for creating the app, so, I am ready to run the base app, how can I do that OFFLINE... I have gradle on my pc as well but  seems I need more stuff or mandatory be online... I already have an android device connected and ready via USB...

How can I run it offline?

Regards from Cuba.
LordFord.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the connection from the emulator to the packager? If that is so, then you are just in debug/dev mode and that is how RN works.

You could bundle your project and that would create a single JS file that the app will read locally, no need for connection.

Now, there is no other requirement for Internet, so unless there is another issue I am missing, that should be it.

Comment: Well, I'l try but when I run react-native run-android it tries to connect to internet and download grade and other stuff... any tips to avoid that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to `eject` your application. [Here](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md) is official doc

But in general if you have emulator and react cli tool already installed it should be easy as

```
react-native eject
react-native run-android
```